# php CANG does not using value 0

Tags: php, generator, zero, alphanumeric

Hi there i have a little issue with my CANG(Complex Alpha Numeric Generator) in php,
the generator is not inserting the number 0 into string.
This is from my DB MySQL
Example :
**AAAAACPZ** next code is -> AAAAACP1
**but it should be AAAAACP0 and after AAAAACP1**
Can somebody help me please to solve this issue?

Search for CANG.php and have look on my CANG class at [here](https://github.com/LukasStribrny/Complex_Alpha-Numeric_Generator/tree/master/v.0.3/).

I remember once i have done this in the previous version,
but after some time i decide it to delete all the codes
and later on i build new versions.
If anyone come up with something let me know.
Thanks in advance

***A little explanation :***
All the generation of strings depends on the settings provided.
For example a have range('A','Z') and range(0,9)
so after every Z should be number zero -> 0 and not number 1.

```
<?php
class CANG {

    public $default_code_length = 1;
    public $default_code_type = 1;
    public $run_default_code = TRUE;
    public $run_random_code = TRUE;
    public $code_max_type = 8;

    public function __construct(){
        /*
        Nothing to do here but if you need to use it with CI must write :
        class CANG extends CI_Library {}
        and remove the double back slash below
        */
        //parent::__construct();
    }

    public function SetLength($SetLength=FALSE){
        if(is_numeric($SetLength)){
            $this->default_code_length = $SetLength;
        }
    }

    public function SetType($SetType=FALSE){
        if(is_numeric($SetType) AND $this->code_max_type>=$SetType){
            $this->default_code_type = $SetType;
        }
    }

    public function CodeCountRange($code_char_range=[]){
        $count_characters = count($code_char_range);
        if(function_exists('bcpow')){
            return bcpow($count_characters, $this->default_code_length);
        }else{
            return pow($count_characters, $this->default_code_length);
        }

    }

    public function CodeTypes(){

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_name'] = '[A-Z]';
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_name'] = '[a-z]';
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z]';
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_name'] = '[0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_name'] = '[a-z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-_]';

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Simple:Capital letters';
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Simple:Small letters';
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Combi:Capital and small letters';
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_description'] = 'Numerical -> Simple';
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Simple:Capital letters(Megaupload.com)';
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Simple:Small letters';
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Combi:Capital and small letters';
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Combi:Capital and small letters plus special chars(Youtube.com)';

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range'] = range('A','Z');
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range'] = range('a','z');
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'));
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range'] = range(0,9);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('a','z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9),array('-','_'));

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range']);

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range']);

        $this->CodeType = $CodeTypes[$this->default_code_type];
        return $CodeTypes;
    }

    public function CodeInput($CodeInput=''){
        if(!empty($CodeInput)){
            $this->run_default_code = FALSE;
            $this->CodeInputOld = $CodeInput;
        }else{
            $this->run_random_code = FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function Search($Value){
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
        foreach($code_char_range AS $KeyNumber=>$KeyString){
            if("$KeyString"=="$Value"){
                return $KeyNumber;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    public function CodeCreateNext(){

    $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
    $code_char_range_start = reset($code_char_range);
    $code_char_range_end = end($code_char_range);

    $code_str_split = str_split($this->CodeInputOld);

    // Starts a search for the next incrementable character, ie, other than code_char_range_end
    // Note that it starts from the last character for the first character
        for($i = count($code_str_split)-1;$i>-1;$i--){
            if("$code_str_split[$i]" == "$code_char_range_end"){
                if($i==0){
                // If it is equal to code_char_range_end and is the first character, then it increases the length and zera
                $code_str_split = array_fill(0,count($code_str_split) + 1,"$code_char_range_start");
                return $code_str_split;
                }else{
                    $n = $i-1;
                    $code_str_pos = $this->Search("$code_str_split[$n]")+1;
                    if("$code_str_split[$n]" != "$code_char_range_end"){
                    // If the previous character is different from code_char_range_end, it increments it and clears the current and subsequent characters
                    // If the previous character is the first one, it also works, because it increments it and zeroes the others
                    if(empty($code_char_range[$code_str_pos])){
                        $code_str_split[$n] = settype($code_char_range[$code_str_pos],'string');
                    }else{
                        $code_str_split[$n] = $code_char_range[$code_str_pos];
                    }
                        for($j = $i; $j < count($code_str_split); $j++){
                            $code_str_split[$j] = $code_char_range_start;
                        }
                    return $code_str_split;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                // calculates the next character, ie, increments the current character
                $code_str_pos = $this->Search("$code_str_split[$i]")+1;
                if(empty($code_char_range[$code_str_pos])){
                    $code_str_split[$i] = settype($code_char_range[$code_str_pos],'string');
                }else{
                    $code_str_split[$i] = $code_char_range[$code_str_pos];
                }
                if($i == 0){
                    // If it is the first character, it means that the others are code_char_range_end
                    // That is, he zeroes them
                    $novo_array = array_fill(0,count($code_str_split),"$code_char_range_start");
                    $novo_array[0] = $code_str_split[$i];
                    $code_str_split = $novo_array;
                }
            return $code_str_split;
            }
        }
    }

    public function CodeCreate(){

        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
        $code_char_range_start = reset($code_char_range);

        $this->code_char_base = [];
        if($this->run_default_code){
            for($n=1;$this->default_code_length>=$n;$n++){
                if($this->run_random_code){
                    $this->code_char_base[] = $code_char_range[mt_rand(0,($code_char_count-1))];
                }else{
                    $this->code_char_base[] = $code_char_range_start;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->code_char_base = $this->CodeCreateNext();
        }
    }

    public function CodeCountNumber() {
        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];

        $character_keys = array_flip($code_char_range);
        $code_characters = $this->code_char_base;

        $number = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($code_characters); $i++) {
                $number = $number * $code_char_count + $character_keys[$code_characters[$i]];
        }
        $this->code_pos_num = ($number+1);
    }

    public function CodeArray(){
        $code_base = implode($this->code_char_base);
    if($this->default_code_length==strlen($code_base)){
            return array(
                    'code_base'=>$code_base,
                    'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                    'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                    'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                    'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                    'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                    'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                    'code_message'=>'is_acurrate',
                    'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                    'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                    'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                    'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                    'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                    );
        }elseif($this->default_code_length<strlen($code_base)){
            return array(
                        'code_base'=>$code_base,
                        'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                        'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                        'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                        'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                        'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                        'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                        'code_message'=>'is_upper_or_full',
                        'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                        'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                        'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                        'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                        'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                        );
        }else{
            return array(
                        'code_base'=>$code_base,
                        'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                        'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                        'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                        'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                        'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                        'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                        'code_message'=>'is_lower',
                        'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                        'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                        'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                        'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                        'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                        );
        }
    }

    public function Generate_String(){
        $this->CodeTypes();
        $this->CodeCreate();
        $this->CodeCountNumber();
        return $this->CodeArray();
    }

    public function Generate_ID($GenerateID){
        is_numeric($GenerateID) OR die('The ID must be numberic!');
        $this->CodeTypes();
        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];

        $one = 1;
        if($GenerateID>$this->CodeType['code_max_number']){
            //Perform reset
            $code_id = ($one - $one);
        }else{
            $code_id = ($GenerateID - $one);
        }
        for($length=($this->default_code_length - $one);$length>=0;$length--){
            if(function_exists('bcpow')){
                $bcpow = bcpow($code_char_count, $length);
                $possition = floor($code_id / $bcpow);
                $code_id = $code_id - ($possition * $bcpow);
            }else{
                $pow = pow($code_char_count, $length);
                $possition = floor($code_id / $pow);
                $code_id = $code_id - ($possition * $pow);
            }

            $this->code_char_base[$length] = $code_char_range[$possition];
        }
        $this->CodeCountNumber();
        return $this->CodeArray();
    }
}
?>
```

How to use it :

```
<?php
include('CANG.php');
$CANG = new CANG;
$CANG->SetType(5);
$CANG->CodeInput('Z');
$return = $CANG->Generate_String();
print_r($return);
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that generating by ID its fine but the issue exist in generating by string.

Comment: the code is in the link above when you click on the word "here"

Comment: Put the code into the body of your question (as text)

Answer (score 0):

So i found the error and the issue its gone forever.
I have removed the each line that includes :

```
if(empty($code_char_range[$code_str_pos])){
     $code_str_split[$i] = settype($code_char_range[$code_str_pos],'string');
 }else{
    $code_str_split[$i] = $code_char_range[$code_str_pos];
 }
```

And here is the tested CODE :

```
    public $default_code_length = 1;
    public $default_code_type = 1;
    public $run_default_code = TRUE;
    public $run_random_code = TRUE;
    public $code_max_type = 8;

    public function __construct(){
        /*
        Nothing to do here but if you need to use it with CI must write :
        class CANG extends CI_Library {}
        and remove the double back slash below
        */
        //parent::__construct();
    }

    public function SetLength($SetLength=FALSE){
        if(is_numeric($SetLength)){
            $this->default_code_length = $SetLength;
        }
    }

    public function SetType($SetType=FALSE){
        if(is_numeric($SetType) AND $this->code_max_type>=$SetType){
            $this->default_code_type = $SetType;
        }
    }

    public function CodeCountRange($code_char_range=[]){
        $count_characters = count($code_char_range);
        if(function_exists('bcpow')){
            return bcpow($count_characters, $this->default_code_length);
        }else{
            return pow($count_characters, $this->default_code_length);
        }

    }

    public function CodeTypes(){

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_name'] = '[A-Z]';
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_name'] = '[a-z]';
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z]';
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_name'] = '[0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_name'] = '[a-z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z,0-9]';
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_name'] = '[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-_]';

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Simple:Capital letters';
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Simple:Small letters';
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical -> Combi:Capital and small letters';
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_description'] = 'Numerical -> Simple';
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Simple:Capital letters(Megaupload.com)';
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Simple:Small letters';
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Combi:Capital and small letters';
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_description'] = 'Alphabetical and Numerical -> Combi:Capital and small letters plus special chars(Youtube.com)';

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_generated_time'] = microtime(TRUE);

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range'] = range('A','Z');
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range'] = range('a','z');
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'));
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range'] = range(0,9);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('a','z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range'] = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9),array('-','_'));

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_char_count'] = count($CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range']);

        $CodeTypes[1]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[1]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[2]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[2]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[3]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[3]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[4]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[4]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[5]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[5]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[6]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[6]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[7]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[7]['code_char_range']);
        $CodeTypes[8]['code_max_number'] = $this->CodeCountRange($CodeTypes[8]['code_char_range']);

        $this->CodeType = $CodeTypes[$this->default_code_type];
        return $CodeTypes;
    }

    public function CodeInput($CodeInput=''){
        if(!empty($CodeInput)){
            $this->run_default_code = FALSE;
            $this->CodeInputOld = $CodeInput;
        }else{
            $this->run_random_code = FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function Search($Value){
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
        foreach($code_char_range AS $KeyNumber=>$KeyString){
            if("$KeyString"=="$Value"){
                return $KeyNumber;
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    public function CodeCreateNext(){

    $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
    $code_char_range_start = reset($code_char_range);
    $code_char_range_end = end($code_char_range);

    $code_str_split = str_split($this->CodeInputOld);

    // Starts a search for the next incrementable character, ie, other than code_char_range_end
    // Note that it starts from the last character for the first character
        for($i = count($code_str_split)-1;$i>-1;$i--){
            if("$code_str_split[$i]" == "$code_char_range_end"){
                if($i==0){
                // If it is equal to code_char_range_end and is the first character, then it increases the length and zera
                $code_str_split = array_fill(0,count($code_str_split) + 1,"$code_char_range_start");
                return $code_str_split;
                }else{
                    $n = $i-1;
                    $code_str_pos = $this->Search("$code_str_split[$n]")+1;
                    if("$code_str_split[$n]" != "$code_char_range_end"){
                    // If the previous character is different from code_char_range_end, it increments it and clears the current and subsequent characters
                    // If the previous character is the first one, it also works, because it increments it and zeroes the others
                    $code_str_split[$n] = $code_char_range[$code_str_pos];

                        for($j = $i; $j < count($code_str_split); $j++){
                            $code_str_split[$j] = $code_char_range_start;
                        }
                    return $code_str_split;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                // calculates the next character, ie, increments the current character
                $code_str_pos = $this->Search("$code_str_split[$i]")+1;
                $code_str_split[$i] = $code_char_range[$code_str_pos];
                if($i == 0){
                    // If it is the first character, it means that the others are code_char_range_end
                    // That is, he zeroes them
                    $novo_array = array_fill(0,count($code_str_split),"$code_char_range_start");
                    $novo_array[0] = $code_str_split[$i];
                    $code_str_split = $novo_array;
                }
            return $code_str_split;
            }
        }
    }

    public function CodeCreate(){

        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];
        $code_char_range_start = reset($code_char_range);

        $this->code_char_base = [];
        if($this->run_default_code){
            for($n=1;$this->default_code_length>=$n;$n++){
                if($this->run_random_code){
                    $this->code_char_base[] = $code_char_range[mt_rand(0,($code_char_count-1))];
                }else{
                    $this->code_char_base[] = $code_char_range_start;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->code_char_base = $this->CodeCreateNext();
        }
    }

    public function CodeCountNumber() {
        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];

        $character_keys = array_flip($code_char_range);
        $code_characters = $this->code_char_base;

        $number = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($code_characters); $i++) {
                $number = $number * $code_char_count + $character_keys[$code_characters[$i]];
        }
        $this->code_pos_num = ($number+1);
    }

    public function CodeArray(){
        $code_base = implode($this->code_char_base);
    if($this->default_code_length==strlen($code_base)){
            return array(
                    'code_base'=>$code_base,
                    'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                    'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                    'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                    'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                    'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                    'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                    'code_message'=>'is_acurrate',
                    'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                    'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                    'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                    'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                    'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                    );
        }elseif($this->default_code_length<strlen($code_base)){
            return array(
                        'code_base'=>$code_base,
                        'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                        'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                        'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                        'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                        'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                        'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                        'code_message'=>'is_upper_or_full',
                        'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                        'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                        'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                        'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                        'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                        );
        }else{
            return array(
                        'code_base'=>$code_base,
                        'code_base_md5'=>md5($code_base),
                        'code_base_sha1'=>sha1($code_base),
                        'code_base64_encode'=>base64_encode($code_base),
                        'code_max_number'=>$this->CodeType['code_max_number'],
                        'code_pos_num'=>$this->code_pos_num,
                        'code_time'=>$this->CodeType['code_generated_time'],
                        'code_message'=>'is_lower',
                        'code_name'=>$this->CodeType['code_name'],
                        'code_description'=>$this->CodeType['code_description'],
                        'code_type'=>$this->default_code_type,
                        'code_max_type'=>$this->code_max_type,
                        'code_length'=>$this->default_code_length
                        );
        }
    }

    public function Generate_String(){
        $this->CodeTypes();
        $this->CodeCreate();
        $this->CodeCountNumber();
        return $this->CodeArray();
    }

    public function Generate_ID($GenerateID){
        is_numeric($GenerateID) OR die('The ID must be numberic!');
        $this->CodeTypes();
        $code_char_count = $this->CodeType['code_char_count'];
        $code_char_range = $this->CodeType['code_char_range'];

        $one = 1;
        if($GenerateID>$this->CodeType['code_max_number']){
            //Perform reset
            $code_id = ($one - $one);
        }else{
            $code_id = ($GenerateID - $one);
        }
        for($length=($this->default_code_length - $one);$length>=0;$length--){
            if(function_exists('bcpow')){
                $bcpow = bcpow($code_char_count, $length);
                $possition = floor($code_id / $bcpow);
                $code_id = $code_id - ($possition * $bcpow);
            }else{
                $pow = pow($code_char_count, $length);
                $possition = floor($code_id / $pow);
                $code_id = $code_id - ($possition * $pow);
            }

            $this->code_char_base[$length] = $code_char_range[$possition];
        }
        $this->CodeCountNumber();
        return $this->CodeArray();
    }
}
?>
```